# Firebase Analytics: How to see list of most active users?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am setting user id for firebase analytics instance using `setUserId` method

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setUserId(uid)
```

Now in the dashboard how can I see who is the most active user so that I can talk to those users to take feedback about my app?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, You are unable to know and you shouldn't do that.
According to the
[GOOGLE ANALYTICS FOR FIREBASE TERMS OF SERVICE - 7. Privacy.](https://firebase.google.com/terms/analytics)

You shouldn't identify your users unless you've told your users before you do that.

Return to your question. 
In firebase dashboard, you won't see it.

Firebase won't collect uesrs' personal data too.
So the statistic is not 100% accurate.

If you still want to know who is the active user, you need

- collect that by yourself
- Define what dose active user mean (Actually Firebase didn't tell us, what is the rule of active uesr)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that as long as you have a privacy policy where you disclose how are you using their personal data(if any), you could use `cloud-functions` to trigger on different events.

You could use `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()` in conjunction with `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).getAppInstanceId()` to send messages to tokens or to subscribing them with a `cloud-function` to a topic "news", like this you can even target `anonymous` users of which you don't really have personal data.

Be aware that in order to use events to record user usage, you'll have to mark those events as `conversion` events.

I personally use `app_remove` and `app_clear_data` to have my anonymous users removed from my project upon triggering any of those events.